# Accessing Domino data from PeopleCode

Tags: lotus-domino, peoplesoft

is there any way to access a Domino server from Peoplecode (PT8.49)? Actually, validating email adresses and sending emails via Domino server are enough, no further functionality is required (no, we cannot use SMTP)...

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

DBa

Answer (score 1):

As far as I’m aware, PeopleCode is a proprietary language, so “out of the box” there’s no integration with Domino.

However, if PeopleCode can consume web services, or bridge with Java, then you have a couple of options:

1. Domino has a Java API which offers the functionality you require
2. Domino can act as web service provider, with said services written in either Java or Lotusscript (a language with syntax akin to VB6). Again, services for the functionality you need can be written easily.

Comment: Peoplecode and do both of these.  The Java code would live within the BEA Tuxedo server that would then call out to the Domino.  PeopleSoft also has integration broker that would call a web services.  So both of these options are available within PS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PeopleCode, but Domino does offer a variety of remote interface options, including http and web services, and COM/OLE (in Windows). If you search StackOverflow for "domino COM" you should find some code examples from .Net, etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not very helpful, unfortunately, as we have our PeopleSoft server on a Unix platform.

Comment: Well, then if not with COM, can PeopleCode make http requests? You can access Domino (do name lookups or send email) via its REST-ful interface or custom SOAP web services. (eg: you can create a small Notes agent to send an email, then call that agent via the ...?openAgent Domino URL command).  Here are some details: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/.  Here's also some sample code that does something similar: http://dominounlimited.blogspot.com/2006/06/post-data-to-domino-agent-using-ajax.html